# Insert data on a SQlite database via PHP (PDO) script

Tags: php, database, sqlite, pdo

There's something I can't explain with PDO in PHP.
I want to insert data on my database (sqlite) called "base.sql" using a php script :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> <html>
<head>
<title> liste </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1> Liste </h1>
<?php

$dsn = 'sqlite:base.sql';
$conn = new PDO($dsn);    

$sql_mins ="INSERT INTO voiture(nom,description,prix) VALUES ( 'Peugeost208','Grise, 90 cheveaux',8500 )";
$conn->query($sql_mins);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM voiture";
$result =$conn->query($sql);
foreach ($result as $row)
{
echo $row['pk'] ." :". $row['nom']." ".
$row['description']." ".$row['prix']." € <br />";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The data that I put on my base using linux terminal are displayed, as wanted. However the data that I inserted with "$sql_mins" and "$conn->query($sql_mins);" is not diplayed.
Somebody knows where's the mistake on my script ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a comma in your description column, you have to escape it using addslashes

Comment: Thanks Chandresh but if I delete the comma, that's the same. The data "Peugeost208 etc" is not diplayed.